# Using Excel VLOOKUP() function across two sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two sheets in an Excel workbook and want to use the `VLOOKUP()` function to search a table in Sheet2 and return the result to Sheet1.  How might I do this?

The data looks like this:

**Sheet1**

```
   A     B     
1  id   name   
2  111  Jacob
3  102  david
4  110  John
```

**Sheet2**

```
   A     B
1  id   Cell   
2  111  03563334879
3  102  03563331234
4  110  03563334222
```

Comment: What is LOOKVP? did you mean VLOOKUP? and what are you searching? What will be the input, and output of your search? you need to be more specific

Answer (score 2):

Short guide for you on `VLOOKUP`, hope it helps.

The syntax for `VLOOKUP` is

`VLOOKUP(Lookup_Value,Table Array,Col_index_num,Range_lookup)`

OR, to start in cell C2 type

- `=VLOOKUP(`
- Then click cell A2 (The value to lookup for this row)
- Then type a comma
- Then excel allows you to click on another sheet to select the table from sheet2, so this would be range Sheet2!A2:B4
- comma
- You want to return the second row from your lookup array so type 2
- comma
- You want an exact match so type FALSE
- close brackets and hit enter

This works for cell C2 but if you drag it down using the cell bottom right corner it will fail in subsequent rows because the table array references are relative and it will move the lookup table reference down one for every cell you move down. You want to make the lookup table array fixed (not the right term) click in each of them (A2 and B4) and press F4, or just add the "$" as below. This fixes the Row and column reference so that when you copy down it will not change these references.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)
```

Now you can drag down to copy the formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vlookup formula. You can get the details from following link:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1